# Cheerio returning undefined on image src

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

When I try to fetch an image of a website in the browser console it works lovely. But as soon as I try to do it with Cheerio it just returns `undefined`, how can I prevent it?

This is the code that returns the image `src` using jQuery in the browser:

```
$('div div figure img').attr("src")
```

But when I try to do the same thing in Visual Studio with Cheerio:

```
var productImage = $('div div figure img').attr("src")
console.log(productImage)
```

It just returns "undefined". How can I solve this?

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Sometimes, the image gets added later via javascript so maybe that's why it's `undefined` using cheerio. cheerio doesn't execute scripts, it just parses what it gets from the response

Comment: You have to make sure that the image is part of the html response and not dynamically added by javascript.

Comment: I’ve tried looking at the HTML and it doesn’t seem like the image is under any script? Sorry I’m new to programming and doesn’t understand everything. I thought it didn’t since Cheerio works in the same way as jQuery in the browser console? Is there any other way to solve it if the case is that it is loaded in later?

Comment: in the browser right click inside the page where the image is (right click in an empty spot) and choose **View page source** or press CTRL + U, this will open a new tab with the raw HTML code source of the page. Try to find the image there, if it's not there that means that the image is added dynamically and cheerio can't help you, you have to find another way

Comment: I can find the image in the source code. It’s in a grid of 6, so I don’t understand why I can’t get it. I get it using both document.querySelector and $.

Comment: Are you sure cheerio loads the response correctly? What's the output of `console.log( $("body").length );`? `0` or `1`? You have to pass a string to cheerio, the response you have could be a [buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html). I know this because I spent minutes this morning pulling my hair not realizing that I was passing a buffer instead of a string to cheerio

Comment: I belive it does since I request other things on the same site, could I maybe add you somewhere if you could maybe help me out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218776/discussion-between-ibrahim-mahrir-and-wulds).

Comment: I don’t know how to do that, sorry. Could you tell me maybe?

Comment: The image is loaded dynamically so your current selector won't work in cheerio. Fortunately, the image url is stored in a meta tag so you can get it that way instead like so: `var productImage = $('meta[property="og:image"]').attr("content");`. **Note:** when you post a comment on stackoverflow you have to tag the person you are talking to using @ so the message shows up in their notification otherwise they won't know, I did not see your above comment until now.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir oh okay, thanks! were on mobile so it didn't work to tag.

Comment: @wulds did you get the image url?

Comment: Answering you chat question: if you stumble upon any other problems, just post a stackoverflow question with enough information and context and tag me in a comment here with the link to the question. I can't promise I'll respond immediately as I'm not active on stackoverflow sometimes, but as soon as I am I'll check it out and try help. Good luck!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir hi could you maybe try to help me out? regarding [fs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63283396/using-fs-to-write-new-files-if-a-certain-url-is-found-and-remove-the-file-if-it)