# Using FS to write new files if a certain url is found and remove the file if it's not found anymore

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, fs, cheerio

I'm trying to write a script, when a new url is found it will turn the url to a hash. Check if the file already has been written it just ignores it, and if it's not known earlier it should be added.

```
needle.get(mainUrl, function(err, res) {
  if (err) throw err;

  if (res.statusCode == 200 && !err ) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(res.body)

    var href = $('div div a').each(function(index, element) {
      urlList.push($(element).attr("href"))

      var url =($(element).attr("href"))
      var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(url).digest('hex');
                
      fs.writeFile('./directory/otherdirectory' + `${hash}`, url, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Hash created: ' + url + ' saved as ' + hash
      });
    }
  )
}
})
```

This is what I've done so far, but this only writes new files. it doesn't check if files already has been added and doesn't remove files that's not found anymore.

So what I try to do:

1. I've written a script that fetches a website for urls.
2. Hash all the urls.
3. Make FS check if file already has been written, if it has just ignore it.
4. If it not is known earlier, add it as a new file.
5. If url isn't found when fetching anymore, delete it from the list.

Comment: The last point _"If url isn't found when fetching anymore, delete it from the list"_ is going to be tricky.Does the directory only contains files that are related to the same website? also by the looks of things, there might be better ways of doing this, so if you could explain what are you trying to do here and why, that would be great

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir 

I want to use this while fetching the same website. So every url that is found on the website is going to be added to the list so only urls from the same website, but as soon that url isn't found on that website anymore it needs to be removed. So I'm only going to store urls that is from one website. So yes, only from one website.

Comment: Why don't you use a text file to store the urls instead of storing them in separate files? That will be a lot cleaner.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir honestly I haven't though about it, would it be faster aswell?

Comment: yeah since you'll be dealing with only one file and you won't need the hashes. It will be shorter too. Are you saving extra data about the urls, or just the urls? Also, are you using those urls somewhere else?

Comment: See the section **Another approach** in my answer bellow to get an idea of what I'm talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/392327) and for that I'm still awaiting the answer to [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63283396/using-fs-to-write-new-files-if-a-certain-url-is-found-and-remove-the-file-if-it#comment111909394_63283396).

With that said, you can simply ignore the existing files using [`fs.existsSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path), if that returns `true` just skip saving the current file, otherwise save it. And to remove files that are not available anymore, just get all the files in the directory using [`fs.readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) and remove files that you whose urls are not in the response using [`fs.unlink`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback):

```
needle.get(mainUrl, (err, res) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    let $ = cheerio.load(res.body);

    let hashes = [];                                                      // list of hashes for this website (to be used later to keep only the items that are still available)
    $('div div a').each((index, element) => {
      let url = $(element).attr("href");
      let hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(url).digest('hex');
      hashes.push(hash);                                                 // store the hash of the current url
      
      if (!fs.existsSync('./directory/otherdirectory/' + hash)) {        // if this file doesn't exist (notice the "not operator !" before fs.existsSync)
        fs.writeFile('./directory/otherdirectory/' + hash, url, err => { // save it
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('Hash created: ' + url + ' saved as ' + hash);
        });
      }
    });

    fs.readdir('./directory/otherdirectory', (err, files) => {           // get a list of all the files in the directory
      if (err) throw err;
      files.forEach(file => {                                            // and for each file
        if(!hashes.includes(file)) {                                     // if it was not encountered above (meaning that it doesn't exist in the hashes array)
          fs.unlink('./directory/otherdirectory/' + file, err => {       // remove it
            if (err) throw err;
          });
        }
      });
    });
});
```

**Another approach:**

Since you only seem to want to store the urls, the best way to so would be to use one single file to store them all instead of storing each url in its own file. Something like this is more efficient:

```
needle.get(mainUrl, (err, res) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    let $ = cheerio.load(res.body);

    let urls = $('div div a')                                           // get the 'a' elements
      .map((index, element) => $(element).attr("href"))                 // map each one into its href attribute
      .get();                                                           // and get them as an array
        
    fs.writeFile('./directory/list-of-urls', urls.join('\n'), err => {  // then save all the urls encountered in the file 'list-of-urls' (each on its own line, hence the join('\n'))
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('saved all the urls to the file "list-of-urls"');
    });
  }
});
```

That way old urls will be removed automatically as the file gets overwritten each time, and new urls will be added automatically. No need to check whether an url is already encountered or not because it will get re-saved anyway.

And if you want to get the list of urls somewhere else, just read the file and split it by `'\n'` like so:

```
 fs.readFile('./directory/list-of-urls', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
   if (err) throw err;
   let urls = data.split('\n');
   // use urls here
 });
```